# Rust Lifetimes: Returning a pointer

Tags: rust

When I write a function like this,

```
fn must_get_env<'a>(key: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    match std::env::var(key) {
        Ok(val) => {
            return &val;
        }
        Err(_) => panic!("Missing required environment variable: {}", key),
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0597]: `val` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:21
   |
19 |             return &val;
   |                     ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
22 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
```

I thought I had a good understanding of lifetimes in rust, but apparently not. What options do I have besides returning a `String`?

Comment: Why do you not want to return a `String`?

Comment: `std::env::var(key)` creates `String` so that `String` gets deallocated when you leave the function unless you return it. you cannot return a reference to it.

Comment: tl;dr: you can turn it into a `Box<str>`, `Vec<u8>`, etc. but those are all somewhat silly responses. Returning a `String` is the most reasonable thing to do, unless you are doing something *very* unusual.

Comment: Thanks, trentcl and belst.  Rust is new to me, but it's starting to make more and more sense.  Your comments helped.